# High chart with angular directive in dynamic ionic slide box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive

I want to create dynamic slide box with high chart with directive . I created directive to show high chart and it is working fine .

> codepen.io/anujsphinx/pen/JbVpvp

Now my json response( vm.items) is of not like that,check requirement

> codepen.io/anujsphinx/pen/oYKwxp

I want to draw high chart of Line ,Pie ,Funnel on different slide box with that json value and direct.